# Pass one of a two pass assembler

Tags: c

The following is the code of pass one assembler in c. This code has a problem i want to get the address mentioned in "output.txt" in hex and not in decimal . How can i fix this ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
    char opcode[10], operand[10], label[10], mnemonic[10], code[10];
    int locctr, start, length;

    FILE *input, *optab, *symbol, *output;

    input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    optab = fopen("optab.txt", "r");
    symbol = fopen("symbol.txt", "w");
    output = fopen("output.txt", "w");

    fscanf(input,"%s\t%s\t%s",label,opcode,operand);

    if(strcmp(opcode,"START")==0){
        start = atoi(operand);
        locctr = start;
        fprintf(output, "\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",label,opcode,operand);
        fscanf(input,"%s\t%s\t%s",label,opcode,operand);
    } else {
        locctr = 0;
    }

    while(strcmp(opcode,"END")!=0){
        fprintf(output, "%d\t",locctr);
        if(strcmp(label,"-")!=0){
            fprintf(symbol, "%s\t%d\n",label,locctr);
        }
        fscanf(optab,"%s\t%s",code,mnemonic);
        while(strcmp(code,"END")!=0){
            if(strcmp(opcode,code)==0){
                locctr += 3;
                break;
            }
            fscanf(optab,"%s\t%s",code,mnemonic);
        }
        if(strcmp(opcode,"WORD")==0){
            locctr += 3;
        }
        else if(strcmp(opcode,"RESW")==0){
            locctr += (3*(atoi(operand)));
        }
        else if(strcmp(opcode,"RESB")==0){
            locctr += atoi(operand);
        }
        else if(strcmp(opcode,"BYTE")==0){
            locctr+=strlen(operand)-2;
    
        }
        fprintf(output, "%s\t%s\t%s\t\n",label,opcode,operand);
        fscanf(input,"%s\t%s\t%s",label,opcode,operand);
    }
    fprintf(output, "\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",label,opcode,operand);
    length = locctr-start;
    printf("The length of code: %d\n",length);
    fclose(input);
    fclose(optab);
```

Output.txt

```
COPY    START   1000
1000    -   LDA ALPHA   
1003    -   ADD ONE 
1006    -   SUB TWO 
1009    -   STA BETA    
1012    ALPHA   BYTE    C'KLNCE 
1017    ONE RESB    2   
1019    TWO WORD    5   
1022    BETA    RESW    1   
    -   END -
```

As you can see on the output.txt file the address mentioned is not in hex . I want to make it a hex value. For instance the addresses mentioned here is

1000
1003
1006
1009
1012

instead it should be

1000
1003
1006
1009
1012

Comment: Check the OpenGroup `fscanf` manual. All whitespace is treated equivalent, so you can use a space instead of a tab. For `fscanf(input,"%s %s %s",label,opcode,operand)` you can expect a return value of 3, but you need to check that because humans make errors. Any other value means either the end of the file or some read error was reached (a negative value) or it tells you how many fields were read (you asked for 3 fields, so you want it to return 3). If you get a positive value less than 3, you don't want to keep assembling this erroneous code, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace %d to %X , the modified code is mentioned below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    char opcode[10], operand[10], label[10], mnemonic[10], code[10];
    FILE *input, *optab, *symbol, *output;
    int locctr, start, length;
    input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    optab = fopen("optab.txt", "r");
    output = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    symbol = fopen("symbol.txt", "w");
    
    fscanf(input, "%s\t%s\t%s", label, opcode, operand);
    if(strcmp(opcode, "START") == 0){
        start = atoi(operand);
        locctr = start;
        fprintf(output, "\t%s\t%s\t%X\n", label, opcode, locctr + 3096);
        fscanf(input, "%s\t%s\t%s", label, opcode, operand);
    }
    else locctr = 0;
    while(strcmp(opcode, "END") != 0){
        fprintf(output, "%X\t", locctr + 3096);
        if(strcmp(label, "-") != 0) fprintf(symbol, "%s\t%X\n", label, locctr + 3096);
        fseek(optab, SEEK_SET, 0);
        fscanf(optab, "%s\t%s", code, mnemonic);
        while(strcmp(code, "END") != 0){
            if(strcmp(opcode, code) == 0){
                locctr += 3;
                break;
            }
            fscanf(optab, "%s\t%s", code, mnemonic);
        }
        if(strcmp(opcode, "WORD") == 0)
            locctr += 3;
        else if(strcmp(opcode, "RESW") == 0)
            locctr += 3*(atoi(operand));
        else if(strcmp(opcode, "RESB") == 0)
            locctr += atoi(operand);
        else if(strcmp(opcode, "BYTE") == 0){
            char ch = operand[0];
            if(strcmp(&ch, "X") == 0)
                locctr += 1;
            else
                locctr += strlen(operand) - 3;
        }
        fprintf(output, "%s\t%s\t%s\t\n", label, opcode, operand);
        fscanf(input, "%s\t%s\t%s", label, opcode, operand);
    }
    fprintf(output, "\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", label, opcode, operand);
    length = locctr - start;
    printf("Code length = %x\n", length);
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    fclose(optab);
    fclose(symbol);
}
```